# How do you throw food?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater

In Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater/Subsistence-HD Collection, you can throw food. This can be very useful, as you can use it too distract or poison guards.

> It is also useful when you get locked in the jail.

How do you throw food?

Comment: I remember it being the same way you throw grenades and other throwables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Survival Viewer and add the food you want to throw in the weapons section. Then, equip the food using R2 and throw it with the Square button.

Comment: How do I put the food in the weapons bar, like what do I press?

Comment: Open the Survival Viewer by pushing Start, select Backpack, then Weapons. Put the cursor on the item you want to use and push X (O on PS2) to add it to your backpack. After that you can equip it with R2 in-game.

Comment: ...and if it's still alive (like a snake) you thow it right at the enemy and it will bite him